# How should I index my tables and build my request to improve perfomance?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm using MySQL. For a MP system, I have two tables (+1 to list the conversations) :

```
_ msg_individus (= members of a conversation)
mi_mcid : id of the conversation
mi_uid : id of the user
mi_ustatus : status of the conversation for the user (opened or closed)
mi_datelecture : the last time (timestamp) the user opened the conversation
```

For now I indexed `mi_mcid` and `mi_muid` as primary key.

```
_ msg_messages (= messages of the conversation)
msg_id : id of the message
msg_uid : id of the user who wrote the message
msg_mcid : id of the conversation
msg_text : content of the message
msg_timestamp : when the message was posted
```

For now I indexed `msg_id` as primary key and `msg_mcid` as an index.

Here's the thing : I want to know if there is a message unread by the user. For that, I compare the last msg_timestamp and the mi_datelecture, if the first one is bigger than the second one, then there's something new.

But for some reason, the performance on this request is very bad and I can't figure out how to index properly and how to build my request in the best way to increase the performances.

This is what I built :

```
SELECT 1 FROM msg_messages as msg
WHERE msg.msg_uid != :u_id
  AND msg.msg_status = "1"
  AND msg.msg_mcid IN (SELECT mi.mi_mcid
         FROM msg_individus as mi
         WHERE mi.mi_uid = :uid
           AND mi.mi_ustatus = "2"
           AND mi.mi_datelecture < msg.msg_timestamp)
LIMIT 0,1
```

I tried to set some indexes on `msg_status`, `mi_uid`, `mi_status` for example but even if things are a little better, performances are sad haha. When I don't compare `mi_datelecture` and `msg_timestamp`, it takes like 0.05sec to process, while it takes 0.20sec when I do.

Thank you for your advises.

(from Comment)  New attempt:

```
SELECT  1
    FROM  msg_messages as msg
    WHERE  msg.msg_uid != :u_id
      AND  msg.msg_status = "1"
      AND  EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  msg_individus as mi
            WHERE  mi.mi_mcid = msg.msg_mcid
              AND  mi.mi_uid = :uid
              AND  mi.mi_ustatus = "2"
              AND  (mi.mi_datelecture = "0"
                      OR  mi.mi_datelecture < msg.msg_timestamp)
    )
    LIMIT  0,1
```

Comment: You're querying on `msg_timestamp`. Surely it's obvious you should build an index on that, yet you seem to have tried everything but.

Comment: Are you looking at all conversations that _one_ user might be participating in?  If so, don't you need a list of conversations?  Or just _one_ specific conversation?  If so, then where is the `msg_id` in the query?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yes I tried it ^^

Comment: @RickJames I actually don't care to know what message or even what conversation is new, in this case I'm just trying to know if the user has a new message whatever it is

Answer (score 0):

Create this index.

```
CREATE INDEX ON msg_individus
  (mi_uid, mi_ustatus, mi_datelecture, mi_mcid );
```

It is a covering index suitable for your subquery. The subquery can be satisfied completely from the index.

If you need more help [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then ask another question.

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried it but I tried it again and even if it is a little better, it's still not-that-good.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is "existence", use `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

Change `IN ( SELECT ... )` into either a `JOIN` or `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`; either is likely to be faster.

And see my Comment that ponders where the query even provides the desired info.

Then we can, and should, discuss indexes.

Comment: Quickly before going to work, I created those indexes :
`mi_uid`+`mi_ustatus`+`mi_datelecture`+`mi_mcid` and `msg_uid`+`msg_mcid`+`msg_statut`+`msg_timestamp` and I changed my query for something like `SELECT 1 FROM msg_messages as msg WHERE msg.msg_uid != :u_id AND msg.msg_status = "1" AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msg_individus as mi WHERE mi.mi_mcid = msg.msg_mcid AND mi.mi_uid = :uid AND mi.mi_ustatus = "2" AND (mi.mi_datelecture = "0" OR mi.mi_datelecture < msg.msg_timestamp)) LIMIT 0,1` and things are already better (0.013sec to process). But I'll try your advises as soon as I got back home

Comment: @Vae - That version introduces a new problem -- `OR`.  Split that into two `EXIST ( SELECT ... )`